# Fix elasticsearch broken cluster within kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm

I deployed an elasticsearch cluster with official Helm chart (https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch).

There are 3 Helm releases:

- master (3 nodes)
- client (1 node)
- data (2 nodes)

Cluster was running fine, I did a crash test by removing master release, and re-create it.

After that, master nodes are ok, but data nodes complain:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.CoordinationStateRejectedException: join validation on cluster state with a different cluster uuid xeQ6IVkDQ2es1CO2yZ_7rw than local cluster uuid 9P9ZGqSuQmy7iRDGcit5fg, rejecting
```

which is normal because master nodes are new.

**How can I fix data nodes cluster state without removing data folder?**

Edit:

I know the reason why is broken, I know a basic solution is to remove data folder and restart node (as I can see on elastic forum, lot of similar questions without answers). But I am looking for a production aware solution, maybe with `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/node-tool.html` tool?

Answer (score 4):

Using `elasticsearch-node` utility, it's possible to reset cluster state, then the fresh node can join another cluster.

The tricky thing is to use this utility bin with Docker, because `elasticsearch server` must be stopped!

Solution with kubernetes:

1. Stop pods by scaling to 0 the sts: `kubectl scale data-nodes --replicas=0`
2. Create a k8s job that reset the cluster state, with data volume attached
3. Apply the job for each PVC
4. Rescale sts and enjoy!

job.yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test-fix-cluster-m[0-3]
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -c
        - yes | elasticsearch-node detach-cluster; yes | elasticsearch-node remove-customs '*'
        # uncomment for at least 1 PVC
        #- yes | elasticsearch-node unsafe-bootstrap -v
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
        name: elasticsearch
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: es-data
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - name: es-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: es-test-master-es-test-master-[0-3]
```

If you are interested, here the code behind `unsafe-bootstrap`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/coordination/UnsafeBootstrapMasterCommand.java#L83

I have written a small story at https://medium.com/@thomasdecaux/fix-broken-elasticsearch-cluster-405ad67ee17c.

Comment: Great help! I wonder why nobody upvoted this solutions up until now.